# Javascript - Remove query string from current url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url

I need to remove query string value from the url once submit button is clicked. Can i able to do this with jquery?

Current Url:

```
siteUrl/page.php?key=value
```

After Page submit:

```
siteUrl/page.php
```

Actually i have landing to current page from another one with query string. I need query string value when page loads first time to prefill some details. But once i submitted the form, i need to remove query string value.

I have tried like this.

```
$('#submit').click(function(){
var newUrl = window.location.href.replace(window.location.search,'');
window.location.href  = newUrl;
return false;
});
```

It makes changes in url as expected. but cant able to get the posted values.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `location.search=''`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately i cant able to do it with javascript or jquery. So i go through with php redirection, now it works.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {
    // actions
    if(isset($_REQUEST['key']) && ($_REQUEST['key'] != "")) {
        header('Refresh: 1;url='.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
}
?>
```

Thanks all :)

Answer (score 1):

How about this one. Hope it helps :)

```
$('#myform').submit(function(event){
event.preventDefault();
var currentURL = window.location.href ;
location.href = currentURL.substring(0, currentURL.indexOf('?'));
});
```

index.html

```
<form id = "myform">
<input type = "text">
<input type = "submit" id = "submit" value = "Send">
</form>
```

Comment: How can i use this? $('#submit').click(function(){
var currentURL = document.location.href;
window.location.href = currentURL.substring(0, test.indexOf('?'));
});
 like above ?

Comment: @SyedIbrahim currentURL stores the current URL you are on, then after submitting you can set the current URL using location.href and assign it the value of currentURL.substring(0, test.indexOf('?'));  . The should solve your problem :)

Comment: @SyedIbrahim Yes, Try that and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Sorry bro, it doesn't work :( I still landing on same page with query string.

Comment: @SyedIbrahim I just updated my answer and it works just fine :). Please take a look at it.

Comment: It works. But my bad, it not fulfill my requirement. :(

Answer (score 0):

```
function getQueryString(url) {
  return url.split("?")[0];
}
var Url=getQueryString("siteUrl/page.php?key=value");
console.log(Url);
```

You may try this for getting url